# Ruby/Rails passing array to case

Tags: ruby, case-statement

Here is the scenario:

```
case code
  when 'www', '', nil
    false
  when 'code1', 'code2'... 'code_n' # The array STORE_CODES contains all the codes 
    true
  else
    false
end
```

How can I use `STORE_CODES` directly after `when` instead of `'code1', 'code2'... 'code_n'`

Comment: I've searched throughly before posting this, could you please explain how is it duplicate of the post mentioned

Answer (score 43, accepted):

just use:

```
when *STORE_CODES
```

instead of :

```
when 'code1', 'code2'... 'code_n'
```

Comment: For those curious, `*` is a splat operator which (among other things) turns arrays into comma separated strings. Good info on this here: https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/